# sending from jframe to java class and then accessing them from other jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So let's say I have 3 files.

- Accounts.java (Account class)
- loginGUI.java (JForm)
- displayAccountGUI.java (JForm)

when I login I input CustomerID, Pin and Account Number. Then the program checks if the 3 values I have inputted are in accounts.txt.

I also have `Account a = new Account();` in both of the Jframes.

In `displayAccount.java` I want to display Account Number from `loginGUI.java` that is being stored in Account.java using `a.setId(ID);` but because I have `Account a = new Account();` in `displayAccount.java` the value set before is being removed due to creation new 'Account'.

Is there any way I can access this value in some other way?

Comment: Create some kind of session object which encapsulates the information you need to be shared between your classes, pass this to your classes so they are making use of it and not creating new instances of objects which have no association with what's actually going on

Comment: This is a relatively basic programming concept, consider having a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've validated the user credentials, create a "session" object, which encapsulates the information you need to share.  It could be the "customer ID" and "account name" information or it could be an instance of the `Account` class.

Pass this to your `displayAccount` class (removing the `Account a = new Account();` and using the passed reference)

How you achieve all this will depend on how you've structured your code.  Me personally, I'd have some kind of controller which displayed a login dialog.  When the dialog is dismissed, I'd validate the credentials, displaying an error message if they failed.  If they succeeded, I'd create a new instance of the `Account` class (assuming it holds enough information about the client), I'd create the "account view", passing the instance of `Account` to it

This is a relatively basic programming concept, consider having a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can create a new constructor for `displayAccountGUI` and pass `Account` as a parameter. It makes sense because in the future you may need more information from the account in `displayAccountGUI`, like a photo or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the privilege to add comments yet, I'll just post it here. I only know two of many ways to accomplish what you want to do to get the desired result.

1. pass the value via a constructor

   `public displayAccount(Account a){this.a = a;}`
2. use setter method

   `public void setAccount(Account a){this.a = a;}`